# broadleaf custom file not found page

Tags: spring-mvc, broadleaf-commerce

I want to add my custom file not found page and for that I added following code in web.xml

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code>
   <location>/test</location>
</error-page>
```

and created a controller with request mapping "/test" inside package "com.mycompany.controller.content" that returns a view string "test". Also I have created a "test.html" inside "template/content" folder. Now when I hit a non existing url i get following error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet mycompany threw exception
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.CategoryImpl.allChildCategoryXrefs, could not initialize proxy - no Session
   at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
   at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
   at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
   at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
   at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:266)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.CategoryImpl.getChildCategoryXrefs(CategoryImpl.java:616)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.processor.CategoriesProcessor.modifyModelAttributes(CategoriesProcessor.java:84)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.dialect.AbstractModelVariableModifierProcessor.processElement(AbstractModelVariableModifierProcessor.java:57)
   at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementProcessor.doProcess(AbstractElementProcessor.java:74)
   at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1016)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:971)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93)
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155)
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
   at org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
   at org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:438)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:421)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:342)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
May 25, 2014 1:29:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/test]
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.processor.CategoriesProcessor' (layout/partials/header:45)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:438)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:421)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:342)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.processor.CategoriesProcessor' (layout/partials/header:45)
   at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:223)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1016)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:971)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
   at org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93)
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155)
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
   at org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
   at org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
   ... 20 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.CategoryImpl.allChildCategoryXrefs, could not initialize proxy - no Session
   at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
   at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
   at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
   at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
   at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:266)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.CategoryImpl.getChildCategoryXrefs(CategoryImpl.java:616)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.processor.CategoriesProcessor.modifyModelAttributes(CategoriesProcessor.java:84)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.dialect.AbstractModelVariableModifierProcessor.processElement(AbstractModelVariableModifierProcessor.java:57)
   at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementProcessor.doProcess(AbstractElementProcessor.java:74)
   at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
   ... 54 more
```

After this I used following code to resolve the exception

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>       
</filter-mapping>
```

Previous exception got resolved but a new exception emerged which is as follows

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet mycompany threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.BroadleafRequestCustomerResolverImpl.setCustomer(BroadleafRequestCustomerResolverImpl.java:62)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.core.CustomerState.setCustomer(CustomerState.java:52)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.core.security.CustomerStateRequestProcessor.process(CustomerStateRequestProcessor.java:134)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.core.security.CustomerStateFilter.doFilter(CustomerStateFilter.java:55)
   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
```

On investigating around this exception, I noticed that "setCustomer" method of "BroadleafRequestCustomerResolverImpl" class is called twice and request reference becomes null after the second call.

Comment: have u tried this in admin application?..it worked fine for me when i configured the error message templates in web.xml..

Comment: @Lucky I have not tried it in admin application. Can you show me some sample code or tell me the steps that i need to take to do this?

Comment: <error-page>
     <error-code>404</error-code>
     <location>/WEB-INF/templates/error/404error.jsp</location>
 </error-page>  sorry i havn't done this in site yet..but in admin this is how i have configured..

Comment: @Lucky thanks buddy got it working on admin will try same on site also. But one vague observation if i change extension of error page from jsp to html, then on 404 error broadleaf controller gets triggered and start performing their operation and throws exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem there is that you don't have open session in view when redirecting through tomcat.
So when you are returning a template from your controller you must be sure that inside that template no entity or lazy relations are fetched.

So as a fast workaround or conclusion I suggest you three different solutions :

1. You might use a template that doesn't use any entity as a model (
   nor fetch it lazy because it won't work).
2. You could add to the model a DTO instead of entity and with this you
   won't need open session in view.
3. You might use a simple jsp/html without using a controller/template
   engine.

Personally I prefer solution 2.

Comment: thanks for explaining the issue and giving different solutions. I have used third option and its working flawlessly :)